# Rails 5: Strategies to handle users saving records with multiple time zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an app that I'm working on that will have nationwide (possibly world wide) customers. I'm dealing with timezones for the first time with this app and it's a bit of a headache. I'm curious on the strategies for dealing with users in different timezones.

Right now, the user is able to select their timezone when they create their account and `Time.zone` is set application wide in the application controller:

```
# application_controller.rb
def set_timezone
  if current_user
    Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
  else
    Time.zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
  end
end
```

I would like the user to be able to create their Event and set the time with their timezone automatically and then have other users in other timezones adjust so they see the proper time.

I'm having a hard time trying to google the solution to this (seemingly common issue) and curious as the strategies to dealing with this. I would imagine Rails has some baked in features.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to split the problem in 2 sides:

1. **Data in:** You should save the events and any other model that uses time in the db using a single timezone (I recommend UTC), that means that every time they create a model, you'll have to convert from the preferred timezone to your db timezone. **Make sure that the app and the db are set in the same timezone.**
2. **Data out:** you'll have to create a method shared across your app that it's in the models, presenters, etc can use and can switch the data from the db timezone to the preferred timezone. **This should be the last step before the data leaving your server.**

The method will have something like this:

```
time.in_time_zone("America/New_York")
```

In this way your app does calculations and all in a single timezone and the user will have them in their preferred location.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to give your method a shot but I seem to be running into a slight issue. It outputs wrong.

[11] pry(#<EventsController>)> params[:event][:ended_at]
=> "05/31/2017 2:00 PM"
[12] pry(#<EventsController>)> to_datetime = DateTime.strptime(params[:event][:started_at], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p")
=> Wed, 31 May 2017 12:00:00 +0000
[13] pry(#<EventsController>)> to_datetime.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
=> Wed, 31 May 2017 05:00:00 PDT -07:00
[14] pry(#<EventsController>)>

If I check with google. Everything seems to check out fine: http://imgur.com/W81qFwV

Comment: Can you tell me the value of `started_at`. seems to me that might be a typo.

Comment: It was a typo. I copied the `:ended_at` and `:started_at` but the error still exists. I put the issue into it's own question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766762/rails-5-not-converting-datetime-object-timezone-correctly Which is easier than trying to squeeze the issue into a small comment.

Comment: I send you the reply, the mistake is that the system runs in UTC but the date is on PDT, that's what I was saying you need to know the original timezone,  first you need to pass from the original to UTC not straight to UTC

Comment: btw you mention that you'll save the preferred timezone somewhere so use that when saving as the original