# Rails 5: Not converting DateTime object timezone correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, ruby-on-rails-5

This issue has been eating away at me for a while.

I take a date time string:

```
[14] pry(#<EventsController>)> params[:event][:ended_at]
=> "05/31/2017 2:00 PM"
```

I convert it to a DateTime object:

```
pry(#<EventsController>)> to_datetime = DateTime.strptime(params[:event][:ended_at], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p")
=> Wed, 31 May 2017 14:00:00 +0000
```

If I run the `in_time_zone` method on the `to_datetime` object it outputs the wrong time for pacific timezone:

```
[16] pry(#<EventsController>)> to_datetime.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
=> Wed, 31 May 2017 07:00:00 PDT -07:00
```

It should read "2:00PM" the same as how it is entered.

If I go to google and check to see if "14:00:00 +0000" is the correct entry for PDT time it verifies as correct:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6fov.jpg

Any clues about why it's not converting correctly?

Answer (score 1):

the error comes that the `ended_at` is been assumed by the system configuration that in this case is '+0000' you need to include the original timezone the `ended_at` is.

```
irb(main):001:0> date = "05/31/2017 2:00 PM"
=> "05/31/2017 2:00 PM"
irb(main):002:0> to_datetime = DateTime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p")
=> Wed, 31 May 2017 14:00:00 +0000
```

Note that this one has already set as UTC since was assumed by the system the timezone

```
irb(main):001:0> date = "05/31/2017 2:00 PM -0700"
=> "05/31/2017 2:00 PM -0700"
irb(main):002:0> to_datetime = DateTime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %z")
=> Wed, 31 May 2017 14:00:00 -0700
irb(main):003:0> new_to_datetime = to_datetime.utc
=> Wed, 31 May 2017 21:00:00 +0000
irb(main):004:0> new_to_datetime.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
=> Wed, 31 May 2017 14:00:00 PDT -07:00
```

***Update***

**@antonio**'s comment mention he was 1 hour off

```
irb(main):046:0> time = DateTime.strptime(date + " Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %Z").class
=> DateTime
irb(main):047:0> time = DateTime.strptime(date + " Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %Z")
=> Wed, 31 May 2017 14:00:00 -0800
irb(main):048:0> time.utc.class
=> Time
```

As you can see these are different classes and that's sign of problems what you can do is use `Time` instead of `DateTime`

```
irb(main):049:0> time = Time.strptime(date + " Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %Z")
=> 2017-05-31 14:00:00 -0700
irb(main):050:0> time.class
=> Time
```

Comment: I'm *almost* there. However, I seem to have an offset by an hours difference.

The strings I'm working with don't contain the '-0700' so I have to format it with the `current_user`'s timezone (currently "Pacific Time (US & Canada)") like this:

`datetime_string = params[:event][:started_at] + " " + current_user.time_zone`
`to_datetime = DateTime.strptime(datetime_string, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %Z")`

If I see how it saves in the console I see `Wed, 31 May 2017 20:00:00 UTC +00:00`

Which is 1PM and not 2PM like the string came in as. What is wrong with how I'm doing it?

Comment: the only explanation I have for that is that when you use the initial conversion `strptime`, is not detecting the summer time change. I recommend you use `time = Time.strptime(date + " Pacific Time (US & Canada)", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %Z")`

Comment: I saw your edit, I'm not getting any UTC offset that you're demoing on your edit. I see yours has -0700 and mine is showing +0000

`[2] pry(#<EventsController>)> datetime_string`
`=> "05/31/2017 2:00 PM Pacific Time (US & Canada)"`
`[3] pry(#<EventsController>)> time = Time.strptime(datetime_string, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %Z")`
`=> 2017-05-31 14:00:00 +0000`

Comment: Not sure there :| if it works I was using ruby 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

If we look at your first attempt:

```
pry(#<EventsController>)> to_datetime = DateTime.strptime(params[:event][:ended_at], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p")
=> Wed, 31 May 2017 14:00:00 +0000
```

we see that `"05/31/2017 2:00 PM"` is being parsed correctly **in UTC**, hence the `+0000` offset.

Then, if you convert that UTC time to PDT, you apply a -7 hour adjustment:

```
=> Wed, 31 May 2017 07:00:00 PDT -07:00
# -------------------------------^^^^^^
```

and the `14:00:00` becomes `07:00:00` because `14 - 7 == 7`.

If you want `to_datetime` to be in PDT then it would be easiest to start that way by telling `DateTime.strptime` that the timestamp string is PDT:

```
no_tz       = '05/31/2017 2:00 PM'
to_datetime = DateTime.strptime("#{no_tz} PDT", '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %z')
# ------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------^^
```

Then you'll get the `14:00:00 PDT` you're looking for:

```
> to_datetime.iso8601
=> "2017-05-31T14:00:00-07:00" 
# -------------^^------^^^^^^
```

Comment: I would like the DateTime to be saved at UTC so that all users have to do is select their timezone and be shown to UTC time adjusted to their timezone.

What changes would I have to make to the code so that users can see the proper time when users select their `Time.zone`?

Comment: `to_datetime.in_time_zone('UTC')` will give you the timestamp in UTC.